# which design considerations justify std::make_heap() to be apparently sub-optimal?

Tags: c++, algorithm, heap

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap) (and the requirement in the C++ standard) `std::make_heap()` takes at most *3n* comparisons, but according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap) no more than *2n* comparisons are actually needed.

What are the design considerations, if any, behind the apparently sub-optimal specification?

Are there, perhaps, algorithms that trade comparisons with swap operations, i.e. can do with (on average) fewer swaps at the price of more comparisons?

---

**For those who want to close this as opinion-based:** I have edited the post to avoid it being opinion-based, by following [this recommendation on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/1023390) and avoiding a *why do we have such and such language feature?* question, but instead asking precisely what I want to know. If you still think, this is opinion-based, please suggest how this can be addressed.

Comment: Why shouldn't the standard allow some leeway? My guess is that there's probably an algorithm that takes 3n comparisons that has lower constant factors than the "optimal" algorithm (at least in certain cases), so the standard gives implementations leeway so they can choose a better algorithm.

Comment: Ehh... Just there is a way to do it in `2n` doesnt mean that the standard should add that as limitation, forcing the library implementation to only use that way. What if memory is limited or there is some other factor that might come into play? Im sure there are more of these functions in `<algorithm>` that have a looser complexity requirement by the standard than can actually be achieved.

Comment: True. I was speaking out of patterns instead of thinking carefully. Consider that this specifies the number of *comparisons*. There are more things to consider other than just comparisons. I was trying to say that the algorithm could be slower or otherwise worse even with fewer comparisons.

Comment: Walter: since most algorithms can be modified to trade space for time, it may be that the more time-efficient one is less space-efficient. That is possibly the case here since Floyd's method (see your wikipedia link) involves building a binary tree first. I can't say for sure since I've been awake for *many* hours and unable to think coherently - that's why this is a comment rather than an answer :-)

Comment: @pax: floyd's method is in-place. "Build a binary tree" means toss the values higgledy-piggledy into the data structure. The algorithm then fixes them up.

Comment: Which is why that wasn't an answer. I need to go home and get some sleep :-)

Comment: Pretty hard to make it more than 2N-2.  I'm guessing they are adding N comparisons of the iterator against end.

Comment: @HansPassant I think "comparisons" refers to data comparisons, not iterator comparisons.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary, but I suspect the thinking related to the fact that the C++ standard only requires that you define an `operator<`, so when/if it wants to determine that `a==b`, it does by finding that both `a<b` and `b<a` are false, introducing an extra comparison. A few other standard algorithms need their bounds loosened for this reason. I don't think the reasoning applies in the case of building a heap, but I suspect somebody loosened it without verifying that it wasn't necessary in this case.

Comment: @JerryCoffin A heap does not need to establish equality, only order is needed: *`f[floor((i-1)/2)] ` does not compare less than `f[i]`*

Comment: @Walter: Yes, that's why I said I don't think it's actually necessary--I suspect (but can't confirm) that it was a matter of somebody noticing the problem somewhere it really was needed, and a mass edit was done without quite enough care about exactly when it was needed, and when it actually wasn't.